# Cannot convert return expression of type 'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection>'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, model, realm

I am attempting to migrate a Swift 2.2 iOS app that I did not write to Swift 3. There are a bunch of functions that use Realm to obtain models and return them in an array. These all worked in Swift 2.x, but are generating the error below in Swift 3. I have also included the associated function definition.

> /SubmissionDataManager.swift:184:16: Cannot convert return
>   expression of type
>   'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection>' to return type
>   '[EntryModel]'

```
func validateSubmission(_ submissionId: Int) -> ([EntryModel]) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let submissionModel = realm.objects(SubmissionModel.self).filter({ $0.id == submissionId }).first!

    let entryModels = submissionModel.entryModels

    // Check for all entry details field which are mandatory and are empty and not hidden
    let emptyEntryModels = entryModels.filter({ $0.entryDetailArray.filter({ $0.entryDetailValue.isEmpty && $0.isMandatory && !($0.isHidden) }).count > 0 })

    return emptyEntryModels
}
```

I'm not sure what the actual problem is, or how I would go about fixing it. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to manage your dependencies? I noticed you're asking a couple questions like this. Make sure your pod file is updated for Swift 3 if using CocoaPods

Comment: try `return Array(emptyEntryModels)`.  If that doesn't work, try `return Array(emptyEntryModels) as [EntryModel]`.

Comment: @vacawama, `return Array(emptyEntryModels)` worked! Add this as an answer, if you want.

Comment: I added my answer which explains how `Array(emptyEntryModels)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is deferring the creation of an array for efficiency's sake.  Instead of giving you an Array, it is providing you with a `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` which is a lazy `Collection` wrapper that includes the elements of an underlying collection that satisfy a predicate.  In your case, it is the Realm elements that satisfy the closure you passed to `filter`.  *Lazy* means that the values are pulled from Realm as you access them instead of all at once.  A `Collection` is a protocol that conforms to `Sequence` and `Indexable`.  A `Sequence` is a type that provides sequential, iterated access to its elements.  So, at its most basic level, `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` is a sequence.

There is an initializer for `Array` that converts a `Sequence` into an array:

```
init<S : Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == Element>(_ s: S)
```

Since you need to return a real array

replace:

```
return emptyEntryModels
```

with:

```
return Array(emptyEntryModels)
```

That will make a proper array from the `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection`.

---

Other examples of using this `Array` initializer to convert a sequence into an array:

```
let digits = Array(0...9)                             // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let odds = Array(stride(from: 1, through: 9, by: 2))  // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```